# Angular only (click) event works, none of (blur) (focus) (focusout) works

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, dom-events

I have an HTML element like below

`<div (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()" (click)="click()" (focusout)="focusOut()">`

And the 4 functions are just to print out info

```
  onBlur(){
    console.log("onBlur")
  }

  onFocus(){
    console.log("onFocus")
  }

  click(){
    console.log("click")
  }

  focusOut() {
    console.log("focusOut")
  }
```

When I click on this `dev`, "click" is printed out.
When I click elsewhere on the page, nothing happens.

Could anyone give me some hints about how is it possible?

`(click)` works fine means that the border of this `div` is correctly recognized.

But when clicking on other areas on the page, shouldn't `(blur)` and `(focusout)` be triggered?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Blur`, `focus` and `focusout` events are features of the `input` element. `DIV` elements don't trigger them. Only exception is when there's an input element inside the div. In that case `focusout` events bubble from the input to the containing div and downwards. `Blur` doesn't even bubble to parents.

So I guess a suggested fix would be to use an `input` instead of a `div` as they're meant to be used.

**Edit:** I was partially wrong. You can make a `div` element also trigger `focus` and `blur` events by giving it a tab index or making it editable like this:

```
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

or:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add focusout on div but need to add tabindex. Just click on div and click out of div.

In html

```
<div (blur)="onBlur()" tabindex="-1" (focus)="onFocus()" (click)="click()" (focusout)="focusOut()">Hiii</div>
```

In component.ts

```
 onBlur() {
    console.log('onBlur');
  }

  onFocus() {
    console.log('onFocus');
  }

  click() {
    console.log('click');
  }

  focusOut() {
    console.log('focusOut');
  }
```

Comment: You can set any number for tabindex, according to your sequence of selection.